# Automate process SSAS tabular model using Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, ssas

I have process that uses Azure Data Factory for pulling data, processing and pumping data on Azure SQL database. At the end the data from Azure SQL is used by a SSAS tabular model. As of now the entire process till pumping data to Azure SQL is automated using Azure Data Factory v2 but I am unable to find a way to automatically process SSAS tabular model. Kindly let me know if there's a way to do the same.

I want it to be triggered somehow by ADF v2 so that the tabular gets updated data as soon as new data is pumped into SQL. As I was not able to do it using ADF v2, I tried using Powershell. The roadblock that I am facing here is, I need to pass two credentials for processing tabular
1.  SQL server authentication for Azure SQL
2.  Windows credentials of one user for impersonation
I am very new to Powershell and having issues in passing both these credentials

Powershell script:-

```
param($ServerName="Your Server Name", $DBName="Your DB Name", $ProcessTypeDim="ProcessFull",$ProcessTypeMG="ProcessFull", 
$Transactional="Y", $Parallel="Y",$MaxParallel=2,$MaxCmdPerBatch=1, $PrintCmd="N",
$logFilePath="Your Path where you want to save the log file")
## Add the AMO namespace
Write-Output "Process Starts for database $DBName :" | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath
$loadInfo = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
if ($Transactional -eq "Y") {$TransactionalB=$true} else {$TransactionalB=$false}
if ($Parallel -eq "Y") {$ParallelB=$true} else {$ParallelB=$false}
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
 Write-Output "Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
 break
}
$DB = $server.Databases.FindByName($DBName)
if ($DB -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Database '{0}' not found" -f $DBName)
 Write-Output "Database '{0}' not found" -f $DBName | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
 break
}
$date_Start=Get-Date
Write-Output("Load start time {0}" -f (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S") )
Write-Output "Load start time: "  (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S") | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

Write-Output("----------------------------------------------------------------")
Write-Output "----------------------------------------------------------------"| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
Write-Output("Server  : {0}" -f $Server.Name)
Write-Output "Server  :"   $Server.Name | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
Write-Output("Database: {0}" -f $DB.Name)
Write-Output "Database: "  $DB.Name | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
Write-Output("DB State: {0}" -f $DB.State)
Write-Output "DB State: "  $DB.State | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
Write-Output("DB Size : {0}MB" -f 

    ($DB.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"))
    Write-Output "DB Size : "  ($DB.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
    Write-Output("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    Write-Output "----------------------------------------------------------------"| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
    Write-Output("DB processing started.   Time: {0}" -f (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S"))
    Write-Output "DB processing started.   Time: " (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
    $server.CaptureXml=$TRUE # Just capture server statements, dont execute them
    #Process dimensions
    foreach ($dim in $DB.Dimensions) {
      $dim.Process($ProcessTypeDim)
    } # Dimensions
    #Process cubes
    foreach ($cube in $DB.Cubes) {
     foreach ($mg in $cube.MeasureGroups) {
      foreach ($part in $mg.Partitions) {
       $part.Process($ProcessTypeMG)
      }
     }
    }
    # Separate step to process all linked measure groups. Linke MG does not have partitions
    foreach ($cube in $DB.Cubes) {
     foreach ($mg in $cube.MeasureGroups) {
      if ($mg.IsLinked) {
       $mg.Process($ProcessTypeMG)
      }
     }
    }

    $server.CaptureXML = $FALSE # Finish capturing statements. All statements are in Server.CaptureLog
    $cmdBatch = @"
    <Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
      <Parallel MaxParallel="##MaxParallel##">
    ##ProcessCmd##
      </Parallel>
    </Batch>
    "@
    $cmdBatch = $cmdBatch -replace("##MaxParallel##",$MaxParallel)
    #$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $currentCmdNo=0; $currentCmdInBatchNo=0;
    $processCmd="";$currentBatchNo=0
    $TotalCmdCount = $Server.CaptureLog.Count

    foreach ($cmdLine in $Server.CaptureLog) {
     $currentCmdNo = $currentCmdNo + 1
     $processCmd = $processCmd + $cmdLine + "`n"
     $currentCmdInBatchNo=$currentCmdInBatchNo + 1
     if ($currentCmdInBatchNo -ge $MaxCmdPerBatch -or $currentCmdNo -eq $TotalCmdCount) { #MaxCmdPerBatch reached, execute commands
      $processCmd = $cmdBatch -replace("##ProcessCmd##", $processCmd) 
      if ($PrintCmd -eq "Y") { Write-Output($processCmd) }
      $currentBatchNo = $currentBatchNo + 1;
      Write-Output("=== Startining batch No {0}. Time: {1} ..." -f $currentBatchNo, (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S"))
      Write-Output "=== Startining batch No $currentBatchNo. Time: ..."  (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
      $Result = $Server.Execute($processCmd)
      # Report errors and warnings
      foreach ($res in $Result) {
       foreach ($msg in $res.Messages) {
        if ($msg.Description -ne $null) {
                        Write-Output("{0}" -f $msg.Description)
                        Write-Output $msg.Description| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
                        } 
       }
      }
      # Reset temp values
      $processCmd = ""; $currentCmdInBatchNo=0;
     }
    }#foreach 

    Write-Output("-------------------------Cube status----------------------------")
    Write-Output("-------------------------Cube status----------------------------")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

    $data=$DB.Cubes|select name,state,lastprocessed
    Write-Output($data)
    Write-Output $data| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append 

    Write-Output("--------------------Dimension status----------------------------")
    Write-Output("--------------------Dimension status----------------------------")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

    $data=$DB.Dimensions|select name,state,lastprocessed
    Write-Output($data)
    Write-Output $data| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append 

    Write-Output("-----------------Dimension related to cubes---------------------")
    Write-Output("-----------------Dimension related to cubes---------------------")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

    foreach ($cube in $DB.Cubes) {
        Write-Output("Cube Name: $cube")
        Write-Output "Cube Name: $cube"| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
            foreach ($dim in $DB.Dimensions) {
            Write-Output("                         $dim")
            Write-Output "                         $dim"| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

        } 
    }

    Write-Output("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    Write-Output("----------------------------------------------------------------")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append 
    $date_End=Get-Date
    Write-Output("Load End Time: {0}" -f (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S"))
    Write-Output "Load End Time: "  (Get-Date -uformat "%H:%M:%S")| Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

    $ptime="Total Processing Time :"+($date_End-$date_Start).Hours+" Hours, "+($date_End-$date_Start).Minutes+" Mins, "+($date_End-$date_Start).Seconds+" Secs "
    Write-Output $ptime
    Write-Output $ptime | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
```

Error message -

> OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; A network-related
>   or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check
>   if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.;
>   08001; Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server
>   [5]. ; 08001.

Comment: Are you using Azure Analysis Services or SSAS installed on a host? If you use Azure Analysis Services then you can use the REST API from ADF2 and process your model.

Comment: I am using on-premise SSAS

Comment: I’ve done this before but it was through an SSIS package. It’s probably possible just through Powershell. Are you running powershell in Azure Automation? The error you’re getting is network, not login.

Comment: As of now I am trying to run Powershell on the same machine where SSAS is hosted. I'm getting the above mentioned error on the local machine itself.

Comment: I guess it happens at `$server.connect($ServerName)`. You've put in the correct server name right? (passed in as a parameter). A good way to check is just put `$ServerName` on the line right before this and it will echo it.

Comment: So, the connection issue got resolved by using Service account for impersonation in SSAS. I am able to process tabular using Powershell.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. I'm not aware of an easy way to call powershell on a VM from ADF. There are a few complicated ways. You could use this to provide a HTTP endpoint that ADF could call https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/simple-http-api-for-executing-powershell-scripts/

Comment: @vishnupriya Please consider posting your solution as an answer- it makes it easier for people struggling with the same issue to find the answer. I'm glad you got this figured out!

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer OP shared in the comment:

The issue was resolved by using Service account for impersonation in SSAS